# C# inputSimulator timer for keystrokes?

Tags: c#, timer, simulation, keystroke

how do I make a timer (cooldown/disable/delay) a keystroke for a limited amount of time?

I'm using inputSimulator as pInvoke and all those are a bit beyond my understanding, I tried it for a couple of hours without success so i decided to use inputSimulator(which took me 2minutes to figure out).

Anyways, it's for a space combat game in C# Form so what i needed was to be able to hit various key-combinations without the program blocking the previous key, did that, now i just need a timer, any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just disabling a boolean for a limited time which is the obvious answer. Instead of disabling a key, you disable whatever action the key executes for a limited time.